# Solr of AWS crashing when ingesting large volume of data

Tags: amazon-web-services, solr, solrcloud

I am using AWS to host a Solr cloud. As soon as I ingest a large volume data to the service. Within a week the service is crashing, but the same is not happening when the volume of data is small

Comment: How does it crash? What does the log show? Are you using EC2 instances and hosting it yourself, or are you using a predefined service (if available)? How are you ingesting data?

Comment: Thanks, @MatsLindh for your reply. Yes, I'm using EC2 instances and hosting it myself. I'm ingesting the data using bin/solr post from the terminal. Currently, I'm not having the logs as I restarted the whole service. The crash happens as in some of the nodes the bin/solr process gets terminated on its own.

Comment: @Ashin the symptoms of the crash you describe are indicative of a JVM out of memory. The only sure way to find out if to check logs. Please have a look at the d logs and if you need help out some excerpts here

Comment: Thanks @ws . I really appreciate your effort